# Linking Files (image, js) in PHP Using Src

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have been struggling to link image and javascript (jquery) files via the src attribute in PHP files. I am linking them at the beginning of the file, before the php tags are opened. The HTML renders just fine, as do the source attributes when linked to an online picture, so I believe the issue is how I am linking my files.

As far as file organization goes, I have a file called file1.php inside Indexfolder. Indexfolder is inside of Mainfolder. Mainfolder also has two folders called Imgfolder and Javascriptfolder inside of it.

I am attempting to link my files like this:

```
<form method="post" name="login">
<fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Javascriptfolder/MyJS.js"></script>

<div class="image1">
<img src="../Imgfolder/MyIMG.png" width=200px height=200px id="img1">
</div>
```

I have been working on this for a while and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong! Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you are using firefox Try looking into net panel of firebug or into network panel of chrome developer tools

Comment: @Kelly, How do you mean linking?

Answer (score 0):

maybe problem is in letter case. Or try full link

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yoursite.com/Mainfolder/Javascriptfolder/MyJS.js"></script>
```